# Could not find the task 'tsc: build - tsconfig.json'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]
Hello I am following this tutorial 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial
to debug typescript but I have encountered error as shown in the screenshot. 
If I choose debug anyway, the debugger works but I cant set any breakpoint. I suspect it has something to do with failing to set up the task file. 
Any advise guys?

Answer (score 8):

Task `tsc: build - tsconfig.json` by default comes from VSCode when it detects the existence of `tsconfig.json`. Based on your screenshot, I can tell that you already have the file. So, it is odd if it can't be detected.

Please make sure the file content of `tsconfig.json` is valid.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "out",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Also to check whether the tasks are exist, you can choose menu **Terminal -> Run Build Task** or press **Shift + Command + B** on MacOS. If correct, you can see two tasks available there as the image below.

[image]

Otherwise, there must be something wrong with the steps. Perhaps, there is an extra space in `preLaunchTask`. For reference, I also copy paste my `launch.json` here.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I am getting this error constantly.

Comment: @Black_Rider interesting, what will you see after you execute Terminal -> Run Build Task?

Comment: Using .vscode/launch.json is fine, but using user profile launch settings will give this error. Still looking for solution...

Comment: worked for me, usually the issue is with invalid configs in tsconfig.json file, if the file has invalid config it wont work. Tweaking the module and output version worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. In my case, the tsconfig.json file was not in the main folder, but in a subfolder. In my case, the working configuration looked like this

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch server",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/index.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - server/tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For other language users, the `tsc: build` command maybe be another command, such as  `tsc: 构建` in Chinese.

my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: 构建 - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: 果然！神奇了。中文包连这些也翻译了。画蛇添足。

Answer (score 1):

When you Ctrl+Shift+B terminal will run `Run Build Task..` You'll see in the terminal

">Executing task: tsc -p c:....

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it."

Then after that double click a ts file and press F5 you will have to select at which environment do you want your ts file to run and then you will see the output in the debug console.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS (but may well be the same on other OS's) what got preLaunchTask working for me, was using both a local tasks.json and launch.json

So my folder structure (pre-build) is:

```
.vscode/launch.json
.vscode/tasks.json
dist
src/index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

My launch.json contains:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "TS preLaunchTask-build",
            "program": "${file}",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**", "node_modules",
              ]
        },
    ]
}
```

My tasks.json contains:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo hello yes working!",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "myTask"
        },
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "tsc: build"
        },
    ]
}
```

And my tsconfig.json contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Usage: whilst within the index.ts just hit F5 with a breakpoint set

I have also included another task, "myTask" you can change the preLaunchTask line in your launch.json to: `"preLaunchTask": "myTask",` (where it will output some text to console to verify preLaunchTask is now working)

That way, if you still have issues, you can see if the issue is in your tsconfig setup, or if it's a preTaskLaunch setup issue.

(I would have thought it should have resolved this itself, but apparently not at the current time of writing anyway - but does force the advantage (for me) of committing debug config to the repo on project basis rather than global config)

Answer (score 0):

because it does not find path of tsconfig file....
see your folder structure whether the structure contains multiple same folder with same name...so y debugger confused to find path....so make sure the devlopement folder which you work on has proper path with unique name no same name with its parent folder and contains tsconfig files...

Answer (score 0):

This happens also if the *Extension Host* crashed. This prevents the task engine from finding the requested task. Usually, you should see a message in the toaster where you can immediately restart the *Extension Host*. After that the debugger and tasks work.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the exact structure/spelling of Task by pressing Ctrl+Shift+B (on Windows) and Cmd+Shift+B(on Mac).
[image: preLaunchTask]

In my case, it was **tsc: build - projectName/tsconfig.json**

Answer (score 0):

Create launch.json inside .vscode in your workspace and set in there, instead of using vscode user profile settings.
I don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to fix it by adding a build script in the package.json

"scripts": {
"build": "tsc --build"

and then from the launch.json I replaced tsc:build for npm: build.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a file `tasks.json` in folder .vscode with the next code:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "tsc",
            "args": ["-p", "tsconfig.json"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: tasks.json file with the aforementioned code content]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after following instructions to set up the Vue.js Volar plugin in [takeover mode](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode), which involves disabling built-in TypeScript features.

I fixed by searching extensions for `@builtin typescript` and re-enabling "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features".